# Can I use the sd card in my pi 3b+ in my zero w?

Tags: sd-card, pi-zero-w, pi-3b+

I was wondering is I can use the sd card I use in my  Pi3B+ in my Zero W?  Let me know! I can always experiment and let you know.  Thank you!!

Comment: I would say yes

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have the latest Raspbian Stretch installed on the sd card - yes you can place the sd card in the Pi Zero W and it will boot.